# Помогите , пожалуйста, с ассемблером в программе турбо паскаль

Tags: ассемблер, pascal, turbopascal

не могу правильно написать программу, а точнее поделить

```
var
s:word;
c:integer;
begin
writeln('найти сумму s=x^3/2+1 при x[0,40]');
asm
mov cx, 2
mov dx, 0
mov bx, 0
@1:
add dl, 1
mov al, dl
mul dl
mul dl
mov bl, dl
mov bl, 2
div bl
add ax, 1
add bx,ax
loop @1
mov s, bx
end;
writeln ('s:= ',s);
end.
```

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, [данный раздел справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  В вашем вопросе не хватает описания, что должно происходить и что происходит у вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov cx, 2
> ```

Записали в cx 2

> ```
> mul dl
> ```

умножили AL на DL, результат положили в AX

> ```
> mul dl
> ```

опять умножили AL на DL, результат положили в AX, то что было в AH потеряли

> ```
> mov bl, dl
> mov bl, 2
> ```

вначале в BL записали значение DL, потом записали в BL 2. Вопрос - зачем записывали DL?

> ```
> loop @1
> ```

уменьшили значение CX, и если оно не стало равно нулю, то начали еще одну итерацию. Вопрос, сколько у нас выполнится итераций, если вы вначале выполнили `mov cx, 2`?

Далее, общее замечание, в ассемблерных вставках вы можете свободно модифицировать три регистра AX, CX, DX. Значение остальных регистров, если вы их модифицируете, нужно восстановить.

Теперь правильный код.

```
function sum: Word; assembler;
asm
  push bx     { сохраним регистр bx }
  xor bx, bx  { обнулили регистр bx. Здесь будем собирать итоговую сумму }
  mov cx, 40  { записали в cx, количество итераций. Одновременно это будет текущее значение x }
@1:
  mov ax, cx
  mul cx      { умножаем ax на cx. Результат будет в паре dx:ax. Но для X <= 40 нам хватит и 2 байт }
  mul cx
  shr ax, 1   { сдвигаем ax на один бит вправо, что эквивалентно делению на 2 }
  inc ax      { добавляем к ax 1 }
  add bx, ax  { суммируем с аккумулятором }
  loop @1     { уменьшили значение cx, и если оно не стало равно нулю, то начали еще одну итерацию }
  inc bx      { мы пропустили итерацию при x = 0. Добавляем значение 0^3/2+1=1 }
  mov ax, bx  { результат функции возвращаем через ax }
  pop bx      { восстанавливаем значение bx }
end;

begin
  writeln ('s:= ', sum);
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, вы меня очень сильно выручили